# How do I stop CSS nowrap from putting a line break in my rendered document?

Tags: html, css

How do i stop `white-space: nowrap;` within a `<p>` tag from putting a line break at the start of the span with CSS?

I want to put ellipses on the last line of a search result excerpt and have it look nice on desktop, mobile, etc.

I've read about solutions that use line height calculations to do this, but it seems fragile and possibly hacky.

My thinking is if I do two areas of content and put the `text-overflow: ellipsis;` on the second one I'll get the effect I want.

My problem is when I put `white-space: nowrap;` on it puts a linebreak at the start of the span. :(

Hat tip to @DaniP for putting the issue [in a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cLk2kx02/1)!

Here is my search result template:

```
<a href="/some-url/" class="search-result">
    <div class="well">
        <h4>title</h4>
        <p>See All Selfies Taken with iPhone Camera
Ready to see every selfie taken with the iPhone camera on a device? Here’s all you need to do:
 1 Open the Pho<span>tos app as usual but tap on the “Albums” button
 2 From the “Albums” view (tap back to Albums if you’re in Camera Roll), scroll down to find the “Sel</span></p>
    </div>
</a>
```

Here is the sass

```
.search-result {    
    p {
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        span {
            white-space: nowrap;
        }    
    }
}
```

And here is what it looks like:

```
title
See All Selfies Taken with iPhone Camera Ready to see every selfie taken with the iPhone camera on a device? Here’s all you need to do: 1 Open the Ph
tos app as usual but tap on the “Albums” button 2 From the “Albums” view (tap back to Albums if you’re in Camera Roll), scroll down to find the “Sel
```

Here is how I want it to look after the `white-space: nowrap;` (no line break)

```
title
See All Selfies Taken with iPhone Camera Ready to see every selfie taken with the iPhone camera on a device? Here’s all you need to do: 1 Open the Photos app as usual but tap on the “Albums” button 2 From the “Albums” view (tap back to Albums if you’re in Camera Roll), scroll down to find the “Sel
```

Comment: I ran it on fiddle, it is not inserting any line break there https://jsfiddle.net/cLk2kx02/

Comment: @AjayPal you need scss to use this code https://jsfiddle.net/cLk2kx02/1/

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't put line break. It creates long non-breakable text line like a "big word", so the previous text breaks. Put `white-space: nowrap;` for `<p>` element.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! I need the wrapping behavior on the p element to get the effect I want.

Comment: Does you multiline text should be presaved as multiline? Because for now it's not and there is no "last line" as you mentioned. Do you want to put three dots at the end of your span element and thats all?

Comment: I want to have a few lines of text (maybe 3?) and then the ellipses at the end of the last line. When on mobile maybe it would be more like 5 lines. I don't want it just at the end because the end can come in the middle of a line or the beginning, etc. I want the ellipses at the end of the last line (even though as you mentioned none exists_

Comment: Like this? `span:after {
 content: "...";
}`

Comment: thanks for looking again. I want it to work like this https://jsfiddle.net/cLk2kx02/1/ but without the line break on the span.